# XSL Delimited Values for HTML Links and their Descriptions

Tags: html, xml, api, xslt, asp-classic

I am trying to debug some xsl code that puts links gathered from an XML Document with their descriptions in a list, it seems to be working, except when handling multiple links gathered from a single string that are delimited with a "|" and "^" symbol.

The XML Line that contains this code is very similar to this:

```
<WebContent>
    <content_type_desc>Links</content_type_desc>
       <content_value>Google|http://www.google.com^Yahoo|http://www.yahoo.com^Bing|Http://www.bing.com</content_value>
</WebContent>
```

The xsl that handles this is like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <!--Links-->
    <xsl:variable name="links" select="//WebContent[content_type_desc='Links']/content_value "/>
    <!--Links-->

                <!--Links section-->
                <xsl:if test="$links != ''">
                    <br />
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($links,'^')">
                            <xsl:variable name="URL" select="substring-after(substring-before($links,'^'),'|')"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="URLText" select="substring-before($links,'|')"/>
                            <strong>Links: </strong><br />
                            <a href="$URL" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="$URLText"/></a>
                            <br />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:variable name="URL" select="substring-after($links,'|')"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="URLText" select="substring-before($links,'|')"/>
                            <strong>Links: </strong><br />
                            <a href="{$URL}" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="$URLText"/></a>
                            <br />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <br />

                </xsl:if>
                <!--Links section-->
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What's wrong with this is that it only outputs

```
<a href="http://www.google.com>Google</a>
```

When I would like it to output

```
<a href="http://www.google.com>Google</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com>Yahoo</a>
<a href="http://www.bing.com>Bing</a>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this has me completely stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are actually only using XSLT 1.0, to solve this you could make use of a named-template which is called recursively.

At the moment, the code is only processing the URL before the first `^` in the code. What you could do is put the main bulk of the code that checks the **links** variable in a named template. Then, in the **xsl:when** condition that runs when the URL does contain a `^` you add a recursive call to the named template, but passing in only the substring after the `^`.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:param name="links" select="//WebContent[content_type_desc='Links']/content_value "/>
   <xsl:if test="$links != ''">
      <strong>Links: </strong>
      <br />                            
      <xsl:call-template name="splitlinks">
         <xsl:with-param name="links" select="$links" />
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="splitlinks">
    <xsl:param name="links" />
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains($links,'^')">
             <xsl:variable name="URL" select="substring-after(substring-before($links,'^'),'|')"/>
             <xsl:variable name="URLText" select="substring-before($links,'|')"/>
             <a href="{$URL}" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="$URLText"/></a>
             <br />
             <xsl:call-template name="splitlinks">
                <xsl:with-param name="links" select="substring-after($links,'^')" />
             </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:variable name="URL" select="substring-after($links,'|')"/>
             <xsl:variable name="URLText" select="substring-before($links,'|')"/>
             <a href="{$URL}" target="_blank"><xsl:value-of select="$URLText"/></a>
             <br />
          </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
       <br />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have tagged your question as classic ASP your XSLT processor is likely some version of MSXML for which there is an implementation of http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html so you could use that.